# RestEasy missing @NoJackson annotation

Tags: java, annotations, resteasy

I would like to ask some help because I do not find the @NoJackson annotation of RESTeasy.

When I post my class to the server I get this error:

> 17:14:57,358 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher]
>   Failed executing POST /core/partners/addnewpartner:
>   org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException:
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: U
>   nrecognized field "partnerentity" (Class
>   com.sayusiando.java.dilib.modules.core.commons.core.entities.dto.partners.restproviders.PartnerEntityDTOClientProvider),
>   not marked as ignorable  at [Source:
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@1aadb3c9; line: 1,
>   column: 19] (through reference chain:
>   com.sayusiando.java.dilib.modules.core.commons.core.entities.dto.partners.restproviders.PartnerEntityD
>   TOClientProvider["partnerentity"])

According to the Internet I should use the @NoJackson annotation in this case, but there is no such annotation.

I use maven and these packages are provided:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-jettison-provider</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

The 2.3.5.Final does not have this annotation. Does anybody have any idea what should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found it! I had to add the resteasy-jackson-provider package and everything is fine!

Note, I really don't like the documentation of the resteasy because it requires lots of time to put the pieces together. On the other hand, during this time consuming "put-the-pieces-together" process I learn a lot.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi SayusiAndo, If I am using Jersey instead of resteasy, what dependency I should add to avoid this error "not marked as ignorable at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream" ?. I have already  added @JsonIgnoreProperties but doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I don't know. I left world of java and j2e a few years ago.